# a 2 distance set has an upper bound for number of its elements

Tags: linear-algebra

Can anyone help me with this problem?

We call a set $A\subseteq \mathbb R^n$ a **$2$-distance set** if for each $v_i,v_j$ in $A$, $i\neq j$, $|v_i-v_j|=r$ or $s$. Find an upper bound for the number of the elements of $A$.

Our Teacher proved that $|A|\le \frac{n^2+5n+4}{2}$ using linear algebra, but I read somewhere that $|A|\le \frac{n^2+3n+4}{2}$. Any good upper bound is welcomed!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The best known general upper bound for the size of a 2-distance set in $\mathbf{R}^n$ is $(n+1)(n+2)/2$.  However, it can be improved for small $n$. For $n=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8$ the exact upper bound is $3,5,6,10,16, 27,29,45$, respectively.  (See P. Lisonek, [New maximal two-distance sets](http://dx.doi.org/10.1006/jcta.1997.2749), Journal of Combinatorial Theory, series A, 77 (1997), pp.318-338).  A recent paper on the subject is 
A. Barg and O. Musin, [Bounds on sets with few distances](http://arxiv.org/abs/0905.2423). Journal of Combinatorial Theory, series A, 118 (2011), pp. 1465–1474.

Comment: Thanks alot. would you please give me a link which I could find and download Lisonek's article?